# How to configure a LinkedIn's application in HybridAuth?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I state that I have created an application with LinkedIn and I am in possession of the key and the secret key of the application.

After inserting the key in the configuration file in HybridAuth (config.php) and after trying to log in with my LinkedIn account, HybridAuth returns me the following error:

*"Error!
Authentication failed. The user has canceled the authentication or the provider refused the connection.*

Original error message: Authentication failed! LinkedIn returned an invalid Token."

What could be the problem?

This is the configuration that concerns LinkedIn:

```
        "LinkedIn" => array ( 
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "key" => "************", "secret" => "****************" ) 
        ),
```

Comment: Where are you using HybridAuth? As a plugin/extension to a CMS or in a custom script you are writing? It would be helpful to see where you are using it so we can know where the error might be coming from.

Comment: I am using HybridAuth on a server altervista with a second-level domain of the type www.name.domain.com, in a custom script php.

Comment: did you solve this? I still get: Authentication failed! LinkedIn returned an invalid Token, best M